# Basics of using prolog swipl-stdio

Tags: node.js, npm, prolog

Taken from https://www.npmjs.com/package/swipl-stdio How do I actually use this when the npm example only mentions a 'call'. How does one create a program and then make a call to that program? Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: I think you just issue calls like `engine.call('consult("yourprogram.pl")').then(...)` and use what's defined in node-swipl ...

Comment: I'm afraid nothing works. Constant errors, nothing is clear. Was able to get a bit closer with `engine.call('assert(m:likes(john,cake))')` but it only seems to work with one predicate. Why do people who spend all this time creating stuff do such a horrendously crap job of explaining how to use it. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Raivo (aka rla), the author of both packages, is a very good developer, most probably your problems come out from basic errors (like any newcomer does, like didn't cosider the execution path, etc), that Raivo didn't considered worth to explain. I'm sure that on (forum)[https://swi-prolog.discourse.group] you could find help.

Answer (score 0):

I had success just using the consult predicate.

```
% program.pl (Place in same dir as the node project's 'index.js')


% Knowledgebase
rank(a, 1).
rank(b, 2).
rank(c, 3).
rank(d, 4).

% predicate library
get_highest_ranking(X, Y, X) :-
  rank(X, RankX),
  rank(Y, RankY),
  RankX > RankY.

get_highest_ranking(X, Y, Y) :-
    rank(X, RankX),
    rank(Y, RankY),
    RankX < RankY.
```

JS uses swipl-stdio to consult the program.

```
// index.js

// Require the module
// (Presumes you've pulled down the swipl-stdio package into the project.)
const swipl = require('swipl-stdio')

// Engine represents on SWI-Prolog process.
const engine = new swipl.Engine()

async function run () {
  // The file 'program.pl' is a short prolog program.
  // (see above)
  const query = await engine.call(`consult('program.pl').`)
  const query2 = await engine.createQuery(`get_highest_ranking(X, Y, Z).`)
  try {
    let result
    while (result = await query2.next()) {
      const {X, Y, Z} = result
        console.log(`${Z} ranks highest of ${X} or ${Y}.`)
    }
  } finally {
    await query2.close()
  }
  engine.close()
}

run().catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

Output:

```
$ node index.js
b ranks highest of b or a.
c ranks highest of c or a.
c ranks highest of c or b.
d ranks highest of d or a.
d ranks highest of d or b.
d ranks highest of d or c.
b ranks highest of a or b.
c ranks highest of a or c.
d ranks highest of a or d.
c ranks highest of b or c.
d ranks highest of b or d.
d ranks highest of c or d.
```

Note: It is possibly you will get a warning `` `-tty` is deprecated.  Please use `--no-tty` ``
That is happening because of a deprecation in SWI-Prolog of a CLI switch used in swipl-stdio.

This PR to swipl-stdio shows what the fix is: https://github.com/rla/node-swipl-stdio/pull/2

Comment: Hi, finally returned to this, think I did what you suggested but I get this error ```Error: spawn swipl ENOENT // Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at: // errno: -4058, // code: 'ENOENT', // syscall: 'spawn swipl', // path: 'swipl', // spawnargs:.... a bunch if you need me to display?``` also no mention of `-tty` anywhere. Can you advise how I can get around more programming randomness?

Comment: Missed that I hadn't had swi-prolog on the system. The basic examples in the https://www.npmjs.com/package/swipl-stdio doc work while trying your code above returns the error `error(existence_error(source_sink,program.pl),_14)` error. Copying the program into the `engine.call()` reuslts in this error `error(existence_error(procedure,rank/2),context(execute_query/2,_32))` Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, turns out it was the directory where I had to put the program.pl file :)